# Can't boot after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 - services failing to start

Tags: boot, 16.04, upgrade

So I have upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 version. Everything went OK,  but after rebooting I've got this screen loading at least 25 minutes.

[image: Ubuntu boot loading screen]

After pressing ESC I can see all these errors!

[image: boot errors]

Has anyone had such a problem? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For your current issue, I would recommend booting into a live usb installation, mounting your old partitions, copying all your data off that you want to save, and reinstall since something majorly borked during upgrade.

Look up using LVM to partition your drives, and make a dedicated data/home LVM logical volume and switch to doing full installs if you can. This will lead to less headache in the future, less data loss, and greater portability and flexibility.

If you would like to take a crack at troubleshooting this. I would boot into a live install, mount your old installation, chroot into it, and start using the journalctl command and systemctl status to see just what those services are failing on. It could be something common and simple, it may not!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/659370)

Comment: I don't see how it doesn't. I provide suggestions and the last paragraph tells how to start going about resolving it.

Comment: @KyleH I agree this is an answer, but I think I understand why people think it's a comment on something else: it begins with "+1 to..." That makes it sound like you are posting to agree with a technique that has already been presented in another post. There doesn't seem to be such a post (though I could be missing something), so I don't think that's what you're doing... but I also don't know what the significance is of that strange wording. "+1" usually expresses approval or agreement with what someone else has said. I recommend editing the first paragraph of this post for clarity.

Comment: Thank you @EliahKagan. I have a brain injury and have trouble reading people and why they do/say/type things. So this was helpful to me.